# While simultaneously sending bytes of packets from the client to the server

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0, rtsp

While simultaneously sending bytes of packets from the client to the server. The server partially loses data. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't. If the client sends data sequentially, then everything works fine. Tell me how what could be the problem?
Below is the class responsible for catching packets

1. the OnClientStreamRead method accepts packets
2. OnDataReceived reads bytes

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using NLog;
using MMLib.Utils;
using System.Linq;

#nullable enable

namespace MMLib.Net
{
    public sealed class TCPClient : AbstractClient
    {
        private TcpClient? _client;
        private TcpClient? Client
        {
            get => _client;
            set
            {
                _client?.Close();
                _client = value;
            }
        }

        readonly byte[] _buffer = new byte[8192];
        readonly object _connectedLock = new object();
        static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        DateTime _lastTimeMessageReceived = DateTime.Now;

        private ThreadingTimer? _stopTimer;
        public int UnitId { get; set; }

        int _resendCountCalls = 0;
        int _maxCountReconnectionCalls = 5;

        public int CountReconnectionCalls
        {
            get => _maxCountReconnectionCalls;
            set => _maxCountReconnectionCalls = value;
        }

        private ThreadingTimer? StopTimer
        {
            get => _stopTimer;
            set
            {
                _stopTimer?.Dispose();
                _stopTimer = value;
            }
        }

        public TCPClient(int bufferSize = 8192)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref _buffer, bufferSize);
        }

        public TCPClient(TcpClient client) : this()
        {
            if (client == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client), "Client is null");
            }
            if (!client.Connected)
            {
                _logger.Warn("TCPClient.TCPClient: client not connected");
                return;
            }
            Client = client;
            Array.Resize(ref _buffer, Client.SendBufferSize);
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            RemoteAddress = remoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
            RemotePort = remoteEndPoint.Port;
            Connected = true;
        }

        public override void Start()
        {
            if (Connected)
            {
                StartReadThread();
                _logger.Warn($"Client already connected, {Client?.Client.Connected}");
                return;
            }
            if (RemoteAddress == null)
            {
                _logger.Warn("RemoteAddress is null");
                return;
            }
            if (RemotePort < IPEndPoint.MinPort || RemotePort > IPEndPoint.MaxPort)
            {
                _logger.Warn("RemotePort is not valid");
                return;
            }
            Client = new TcpClient();
            Client.SendBufferSize = _buffer.Length;
            try
            {
                Client.BeginConnect(RemoteAddress, RemotePort, OnClientConnect, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Warn($"CONNECTION NOT ESTABLISHED TO {Name} {RemoteAddress}:{RemotePort}");
                _logger.Trace(e);
            }
        }

        public override void Stop(DisconnectReason reason = DisconnectReason.User)
        {
            _logger.Debug($"TCPClient.Stop invoked {RemoteAddress}:{RemotePort}");
            if (Connected)
            {
                DisconnectReason = reason;
                lock (_connectedLock)
                {
                    Connected = false;
                    Client = null;
                }
            }
            StopResendConnectionReqTimer();
            StopTimer?.Dispose();
        }

        public override void Send(byte[] data)
        {
            if (OfflineMode)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Client != null)
                    {
                        Client!.GetStream().BeginWrite(data, 0, data.Length, OnClientStreamWrite, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.Warn("Client is null");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.Warn(e);
                    Stop(DisconnectReason.Remote);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Warn("Client is not connected");
            }
        }

        public override void OnResendConnectionReq()
        {
            if (_resendCountCalls > _maxCountReconnectionCalls)
            {
                _resendCountCalls = 0;
                Stop();
                return;
            }

            _resendCountCalls++;
            _logger.Debug("Call OnResendConnectionReq");
            Send(ConnectionReqQueue.Last().GetBytes());
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose();
            Stop();
        }

        void StartReadThread()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    _lastTimeMessageReceived = DateTime.Now;
                    StopTimer = ThreadingTimer.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        var diff = DateTime.Now - _lastTimeMessageReceived;
                        if (diff > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
                        {
                            _logger.Warn($"Disconnect client because of timeout. Delta: {diff:c}");
                            Stop(DisconnectReason.Remote);
                        }
                    }, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                    if (Client != null)
                    {
                        Client!.GetStream().BeginRead(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, OnClientStreamRead, null);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Warn(e);
                Stop(DisconnectReason.Remote);
            }
        }

        void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            lock (_connectedLock)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Client != null)
                    {
                        Client!.EndConnect(result);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.Warn($"CONNECTION NOT ESTABLISHED TO {Name} {RemoteAddress}:{RemotePort}");
                    //_logger.Trace(e);
                    return;
                }
                Connected = true;
                StartReadThread();
            }
        }

        void OnClientStreamRead(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            //_logger.Info($"Connected = {Connected}");
            if (Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    int numBytesRead = Client!.GetStream().EndRead(result);
                    //_logger.Info($"EndRead numBytesRead = {numBytesRead} from {RemoteAddress}:{RemotePort}");
                    if (numBytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        OnDataReceived(_buffer, numBytesRead);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.Info($"Stop TCPClient ({RemoteAddress}:{RemotePort}) because numBytesRead ({numBytesRead}) < 0");
                        Stop(DisconnectReason.Local);
                        return;
                    }
                    Client?.GetStream().BeginRead(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, OnClientStreamRead, null);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    _logger.Trace(e);
                    Stop(DisconnectReason.Remote);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.Warn(e);
                    Stop(DisconnectReason.Remote);
                }
            }
        }

        void OnClientStreamWrite(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            if (!Connected) { return; }
            try
            {
                Client!.GetStream().EndWrite(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Warn(e);
                Stop(DisconnectReason.Remote);
            }
        }

        public override void Send(string data)
        {
            if (!Connected || OfflineMode)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var tw = Client!.GetStream();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Client.GetStream());
                sw.WriteLine(data);
                sw.Flush();
                //client.GetStream().BeginWrite(data, 0, data.Length, OnClientStreamWrite, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Warn(e);
                Stop(DisconnectReason.Remote);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought the problem was in the byte reading algorithm itself, but everything works fine there. I tried to add several threads, it didn't help either. I can't even guess what the problem is.